# How to create subfolders for entries?

Tags: entries

I am very new to Craft CMS and just testing out the CMS. In our old system we had 2 levels of virtual folders and I need to keep that structure. I don't see anything that would correspond to that in Craft. Is there anything that would let me create 2 levels of folders?

Answer (score 2):

If you use make your section a Structure, it will allow a hierarchy of entries.

See the [docs on section types](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types) to learn more about the different types of sections in Craft.

Comment: I have created a structure but I wasn't able to locate the option to create the hierarchy. Do you have rough steps so I can follow them. (As I said I have no idea what I am doing so I really appreciate your help).

Comment: If you view the structured section on the Entry index page (`admin/entries`) you can drop and drop the entries around to create hierarchy.

Comment: You may need to update the Max Levels field in the section settings as well, if that for some reason got set to 1.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel - I have set it to 2.

Comment: @BradBell this is what I want it to be [like this screenshot](http://imgur.com/S2XIbqI)

I want articles to be inside of the folders and creating a relationship using structure isn't helpful or at least that's how I see it.